# In timevis + Shiny, can I do operations with input variable input$mytime_window?

Tags: r, shiny

In the R package timevis, the input value `input$mytime_window` "will return a 2-element vector containing the minimum and maximum dates currently visible in the timeline."  I'd like to add five days to the minimum value and use the result in the `setWindow()` function, which itself will be part of an `observeEvent`. The timeline view would then ideally jump to the new date range.

In my experiments, `setWindow()` will set a view with the `input$mytime_window[1]` value as, for example, the start date, then I can use a date string or a function like `Sys.Date()` as the end date, and get the expected result. But I can't seem to be able to use operators or functions on the `input$mytime_window` value. All my attempts to find out the value of `input$mytime_window` reveal a value of null.

And even if I'm asking the impossible, I'm likely pretty confused about  `input$mytime_window`'s value is and how it works; I'd like to understand that better.

Minimal code below:

```
library(shiny)
library(timevis)

# Minimal example derived from https://daattali.com/shiny/timevis-demo/

data <- data.frame(
  id      = 1:4,
  content = c("Item one", "Item two",
              "Ranged item", "Item four"),
  start   = c("2016-01-10", "2016-01-11",
              "2016-01-20", "2016-02-14 15:00:00"),
  end     = c(NA, NA, "2016-02-04", NA)
)

ui <- fluidPage(

  actionButton("action", label = "Action"),

  timevisOutput("timeline")

)

server <- function(input, output) {

      output$timeline <- renderTimevis({
        timevis(data)
      })

      # Trying to use input$mytime_window as a value in setWindow()
      # The code below gives no result
      # But replace the line with: 
      # setWindow("timeline", input$mytime_window[1], Sys.Date())
      # And I get an expected result (just not the one I want)

      observeEvent(input$action, {
        setWindow("timeline", input$mytime_window[1], input$mytime_window[1]+5)
      })

  }

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I have also tried converting input$mytime_window and adding it to days(5) with package lubridate. Both produce error messages.

Thanks for any help, and yes, this is my first post so I'll celebrate that even if I don't get a solution!

Comment: You should use input$timeline_window to refer to the input values because 'timeline' is the id as you defined in timevisOutput("timeline")

Comment: Yes, that works. The line in question now reads: ````setWindow("timeline", input$timeline_window[1], as.Date(input$timeline_window[2])+(5))````. Odd that the wrong input variable gave the right answer in come cases, but it won't bother me moving forward. Thanks @KeqiangLi !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment provided by @KeqiangLi answered this question. The line that needed help now reads:

`setWindow("timeline", input$timeline_window[1], as.Date(input$timeline_window[1])+5)`